# XCeed DataGrid for WPF v4.x: Accessing Excel like filters

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I am using XCeed DataGrid for WPF 4.x. I have created excel like drop down filters using **view's ItemProperties**.

1. Let’s say there is a single column in data grid with values 1,1,0,1.
2. Now I apply excel like filter
   [image]
3. Now there will be rows with value 1 in the data grid.
4. **Question:** How to find values checked in this drop down`(read)`? And also how to set these check boxes from code behind`(write)`?

> **Main purpose:** To retain previous excel like filter applied by user when data grid item source is changed.
>   *[In case of above example after #2, if I change items source from {1,1,0,1} to {0,0,0,0} then user should not be able to see even a single row in grid]*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by accessing the AutoFilterValues collection on the underlying DataGridCollectionView in which the DataGridControl is bound.

Lets say your DataGridControl instance is "grid"

read:

( grid.ItemsSource as DataGridCollectionView ).AutoFilterValues[ "column header" ]

write: 
 ( grid.ItemsSource as DataGridCollectionView ).AutoFilterValues["column header"].Add(0);